# Como fazer com que um usuário autenticado veja as postagens de outro usuário tbm autenticado?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Quando pego a referencia do nó no banco e uso o child para retornar os dados do usuário atual, funciona legal, mas não sei como implementar o retorno de dados(postagens) de outros usuários autenticados no app.

```
postagemRef = database.getReference("postagens").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

OBs: Estou usando `dataBinding` para exibir os dados na tela principal, que seria uma espécie de feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça desta forma:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("postagens")
```

e depois no addListenerForSingleValueEvent, você vai ter que converter dentro de um loop pegando todas as referencias para o seu tipo e tratar. Somente da uma pensada, pois as postagens você vai ter que adicionar um novo listener pois da forma que implementou o banco, vc vai ter que pegar os usuarios com postagens, e depois as postagens. É melhor nas postagens, a key do chave ser o ID da postagem, e ter o usuario dentro dessa key.

Me corrija se estiver errado, mas sua chave está

```
postagens
 - usuario(key)
  - Postagem em Sí
```

deveria ser

```
postagens
 - Postagem (id)
  - Dados da postagem, com uma key sendo o usuario.
```